# Beautiful visualization of narrated sentences (presentation video)

Tags: presentation, closed-captions, transcription

I've written a long list of soothing thoughts that I want to make into a video that will help my clients relax and recenter in a meditative way.

I *could* make a barebones PowerPoint presentation that features 1 sentence per slide and then record my narration of it.

Having the text both visible and audible is nice.

But barebones PowerPoint is boring.

I love the idea of having a beautiful, dynamic presentation like this one: https://prezi.com/presentation-template/creativity-paint/

But that tool isn't quite suited for my purposes because I'm not making a presentation that is structured into different topics and subtopics. (I tried to force my list of sentences into a structure artificially, but it was taking too long in Prezi and still didn't even look good since it's not meant to handle full sentences.)

Instead, I have a long bullet list of sentences that I want to read aloud while the words appear on the screen in pleasant and entertaining way.

Maybe fading in, sliding in, zooming in, etc.

What tools could I use? (Ideally not more complicated or time-consuming than PowerPoint)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) or similar to create named or numbered audio clips (with a matching list of the texts) possibly mixing it with some suitable soothing background sounds (e.g. Whale Song or Pan Pipes).
Then you can use [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) to create text frames for each text, *possibly overlaying on a suitable image,* and to stretch that single frame to a video clip of the same length as the matching audio clip and arrange them in a specified or randomized order into a movie file.

To use MoviePy you will need [python](https://www.python.org/) installed and a number of dependencies *automatically installed during `pip install moviepy`* and for this specific use you will need the optional [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) installed *and, if you are on Windows, [added to the configuration](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html#other-optional-but-useful-dependencies).*

MoviePy also used FFMPEG but downloads it for you on the first use.

The good news is that all of the software mentioned above is:

- very flexible, *(e.g. you can easily create numerous variations)*
- completely free *both gratis & open source*
- available for Windows, Mac & Linux *plus a number other platforms - there is even a docker image!*

Comment: I'm familiar with Audacity and FFMpeg and use them frequently. I hadn't heard of MoviePy and am generally not big into Python, but this is good to know about and might become useful for something else. I think it sounds like more work than I was anticipating for this particular project, but +1 anyway. Thanks.